# How in Linux leave a child process in foreground after the parent dies?

Tags: c++, c, linux, shell

Let's say I have a Linux program that creates a child process then dies, the child continues. When I start this program the shell shows the prompt right after the parent exits. How should I change my program so that shell leaves the child in foreground?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    switch (fork())
    {
    case -1:
        perror("fork");
        return 1;
    case 0: // child
        sleep(seconds(5));
        printf("%07u %s: Process group ID = %d\n", getpid(), currTime("%T").c_str(), getpgrp());
        printf("%07u %s: Foreground process group ID = %d\n", getpid(), currTime("%T").c_str(), tcgetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO));
        break;
    default: // parent
        printf("%07u %s: Process group ID = %d\n", getpid(), currTime("%T").c_str(), getpgrp());
        printf("%07u %s: Foreground process group ID = %d\n", getpid(), currTime("%T").c_str(), tcgetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO));
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is how shell session looks like if I start the above:

```
$ ./test
0007016 22:57.665929: Process group ID = 7016
0007016 22:57.666362: Foreground process group ID = 7016
$ 0007017 23:02.666229: Process group ID = 7016
0007017 23:02.666703: Foreground process group ID = 27254
```

What I would like to have:

```
$ ./test
0007016 22:57.665929: Process group ID = 7016
0007016 22:57.666362: Foreground process group ID = 7016
0007017 23:02.666229: Process group ID = 7016
0007017 23:02.666703: Foreground process group ID = 7016

$
```

Comment: use exec() instead of fork(), so the child process completely replaces the "parent"?

Comment: Slava, can't be a duplicate of this - the question is exactly the opposite, how one DOES NOT create a daemon :)

Comment: I'd say, do not exit from the parent until all it's children are done. Good manners anyway unless you are doing a daemon, which you obviously don'

Comment: @SergeyA hmm "How should I change my program so that shell leaves the child in foreground?" sounds like a daemon

Comment: In my real case scenario the child must wait for the parent to exit.

Comment: It would sound like demon if I asked about background, not foreground.

Comment: @noxmetus your scenario is wrong, parent should wait for child to exit, not the way around

Comment: @Slava, like I said - exactly the opposite of it. Daemons **are not** foreground processess.

Comment: No, my scenario is not wrong.

Comment: @noxmetus yes it is, as it is against how system works. if parent terminates orphan becomes a child of PID 1, so that will not work

Comment: @noxmetus, may be it is not wrong, but I doubt it is doable. In *unix parent-child relationship between processess are strict, as well as their responsibilities.

Comment: @Slava it is not. It's not against how system works.

Comment: @noxmetus when parent exits PPID is changed to 1, not PID

Comment: I am fine with PPID = 1.

Comment: then parent is init not shell. and shell would not see your process as a child. why don't you use exec() btw as Marc suggested?

Comment: It's simply not possible for the child to move into the foreground when the parent exits. The foreground process has to be a child of the shell, and the process created by `fork` is the shell's grandchild.

Comment: @Barmar I don't understand. "has to be a child" and "is the shell's grandchild" contradict each other, since child != grandchild.

How about tell the shell not to change the foreground process group ID. Is it possible or it won't help?

Comment: I'm not contradicting myself. The shell creates a process to run the program, that process is a child of the shell. The program then calls `fork` to create a new process, that process is a child of the program, a grandchild of the shell.

Comment: Process groups are irrelevant. A process can only wait for its own children. Unix doesn't provide any way for a process to wait for a grandchild to exit, and there's no way for the grandchild to become a child.

Comment: Check if `SIGCONT` can bring the forked child process back to foreground. I don't think it will work but you can try.

Comment: @Barmar has a good point that the grandchild process will get adopted by `init` and shell will not be able to steal the grandchild which is now the child of `init`. If shell successfully steals the child, the kernel is broken.

Comment: Why do you need the client to wait for the parent?  What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?  Knowing this, we might be able to suggest a better approach.

Comment: The scenario is the program tests HW. Under certain conditions we would like to restart the testing. Because of the reasons I can't control the program must gracefully exit before restart. Restart also has to happen transparently to the user, i.e. no shell scripts. So idea was to start a new process in the end, make the child wait for the parent to exit and then continue. It works, only the child continues in the background.

Comment: I think I'll implement a single controller process that starts and restarts children.

Comment: killing the parent before the child exits (or is killed) is a good way to create `zombie` processes.  Such processes are very difficult to eliminate without rebooting the OS.   Why not have the parent perform a `waitpid()` on the child?

Comment: (i) I think zombie is created in the opposite situation: child exited, parent is alive, but didn't perform wait operation. When parent exits with alive child the child gets adopted by init. init does the reaping when the child exits. No zombies. (ii) Because it's not what I need.

Answer (score 1):

> How should I change my program so that shell leaves the child in
>   foreground?

Being *in foreground* means *belonging to the foreground process group on the controlling terminal*. Now, the shell changes the foreground process group with the execution of your program - when starting the program, the foreground process group is set to the program's process group, and after the parent's termination, the shell sets the foreground process group back to its own group.
There is nothing the parent in your program could do to cause the shell to leave the child in the foreground after the parent's termination. Every change the parent would make to the foreground process group were undone by the shell immediately after the parent exits.
What's more, while the child could join the shell's process group and thereby become a member of the foreground process group after the parent's termination, this wouldn't achieve what you actually want (as opposed to what you asked for) - the shell would still issue its input prompt right after the parent exits, since it plainly waits only for the parent, not for the child.